# To hide style code in head from source code

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header

When I look to source code of my website, i can see there:

```
<head>
....   
 <style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
    body.custom-background { background-image: url('http://ali-coupons.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/ali-background.png'); background-repeat: repeat; background-position: top left; background-attachment: scroll; }
    </style>
...
</head>
```

I have not it in header.php. What should I do to remove it from source code?
My website on Wordpress.

Comment: Search all the files, themes for the line of code. I guess it is generated from the `wp-admin`. Most of the themes have it.

Comment: You should probably consider asking at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi search for your code snippet on this thread: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-do-i-do-get-this-effect?replies=29

I reckon if you go to wp-admin/Appearance/Customize there's a Background Colour setting, turn it off and that code in your head should go away.

Comment: Thank you, Nathaniel. I gone to wp-admin/Appearance/Customize and remove Background Color and after i gone to my main.css and written it there..Now i can't see this code in source code!!

Comment: No worries! :) Glad I could be of service.